# Windows 7 + ChefDK | kitchen converge failing with Net::SSH::Disconnect

Tags: windows, chef-infra, chef-solo, net-ssh

From regular windows 7 `cmd` I have generated a boilerplate chef cookbook with `chef generate cookbook test`. I have vagrant, virtualbox and my local .box file loaded and can see it when executing `vagrant box list`. When trying to run `kitchen converge` it fails with:

```
[SSH] connection failed, retrying <#<Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host>>
```

I've tried all manner of additions to the Vagrantfile located within .kitchen (generated automatically) and nothing seems to work.

Virtualbox is Centos 6.5 (64bit)

`kitchen login` fails as well even though the vm is listed as running.

Comment: What OS/vbox image are you running inside Vagrant?

Comment: Virtualbox is Centos 6.5 (64bit) @coderanger

Comment: Which version of Chef-DK are you using?